# flask REST API with multithreading is not working

Tags: python, flask, python-multithreading

I have designed a REST API which receives inputs through POST requests and then applies some logic to the inputs and returns to the callback uri which is part of the inputs.
This design was working fine for single input, but then i want to implement multithreading so that i can handle multiple POST requests. I have tried using **'app.run(threaded=True)'** but was not successful.

I am running this code on linux platform. Not sure what is wrong in the following code, and am not so good at using threads in python, would appreciate if someone can let me know where the issue is:

I am able to get the '200' response once there is a POST request and the inputs are appended to '*inp_params*', after which there is no processing in the thread.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import time
import json
import os
import threading
import Queue

import test_func_module as tf

app = Flask(__name__)


inp_params = []
# Create the queue and threader
q = Queue.Queue()

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'] )
def get_data():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return 'RESTful API'
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        global inp_params

        inputs = {"fileName": request.json["fileName"], "fileId": request.json["fileId"], "ModuleId": request.json["ModuleId"], "WorkflowId": request.json["WorkflowId"],"Language": request.json["Language"], "callbackuri": request.json["callbackuri"]}

        inp_params.append(inputs)
        return '200'

def test_integrate(worker):
    TF_output = tf.test_func(worker)
    return TF_output

def threader():
    while True:
        # gets an worker from the queue
        worker = q.get()
        # Run the example job with the avail worker in queue (thread)
        test_integrate(worker)
        # completed with the job
        q.task_done()


if __name__ == '__main__':.
    for worker in inp_params:
        q.put(worker)

    for x in range(4): #4 cores
         t = threading.Thread(target=threader)
         # classifying as a daemon, so they will die when the main dies
         t.daemon = True
         # begins, must come after daemon definition
         t.start()

    # wait until the thread terminates.
    q.join()
    app.run(threaded=True)
```

Comment: What seems to not be working with `app.run(threaded=True)`?

Comment: The test_integrate() is not being called, I suppose the code in if __name__ == '__main__': block seems to be some issue the threading part. I have tried to put app.run(threaded=True)   in the first line of the if block but even that does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

@Shilparani Since you mentioned

> I have tried using 'app.run(threaded=True)' but was not successful.

May not be exact answer for your question but I would like to share my experience for achieving concurrency through uwsgi/gunicorn : 
Keep it simple by coding Flask for REST endpoints and move ***Multithreading*** , ***MultiProcessing*** logic to gunicorn or uwsgi where you can mention threads and workers which help for achieving *concurrency* , *parallelism* if that's what you are trying to achieve.

> gunicorn -b localhost:8080 -w 4 -t 4 app:app

Based on your need and operations:

- If tasks are CPU intensive try to keep #workers as #CPU-cores
- If tasks are I/O intensive may be safe to try with more threads